# How can I select only successful values from leakcheck output?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, json

I have these results that came from leakcheck. How do I properly  exclude "false" results and still include the email using bash

```json
test1@email.com
{"success":false,"error":"Not found"}
 
test2@email.com
{"success":false,"error":"Not found"}
 
test3@email.com
{"success":false,"error":"Not found"}
 
test4@email.com
{"success":true,"found":1,"passwords":1,"sources":[{"name":"LinkedIn.com","date":"2012-05"}]}
 
test5@email.com
{"success":true,"found":1,"passwords":1,"sources":[{"name":"LinkedIn.com","date":"2011-05"}]}
```

This is generated by the following `bash` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
 
for i in $(cat $emails):
do echo $i; curl -s "https://leakcheck.io/api/public?key=<api-key>&check=$i"; echo; sleep 0.5; echo;
done
```

Comment: This looks like broken JSON. Is this the original data or have you post-processed it somehow?

Comment: Post processed, I created a bash script which curls into the api of leakcheck and checks the list of emails that I have provided

Comment: Can you show the non-processed JSON data? That would be infinitely much easier to work with.

Comment: @Kusalananda, the non processed json is this "{"success":true,"found":1,"passwords":1,"sources":[{"name":"LinkedIn.com","date":"2011-05"}]}" excluding the email

Comment: And how do you match the email to the objects in the JSON? That data alone could easily be filtered using `jq -R 'fromjson|select(.success)'` assuming the data is encoded as JSON strings as you show in the comment, or `jq 'select(.success)'` if it's plain JSON..

Comment: here is my bash script that executes curl to leakcheck's API, https://pastebin.com/dFKMy1Wa. It just appends the email to the end of the curl and it will check all emails from the list individually. I hope it makes sense

Comment: Instead of "exclude false", would it also work with "include only true"? Would something such as `grep -B 1 '"success":true'` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of outputting the address and querying the API, output the address and the result of the API call only if the call is successful:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r addr; do
    reply=(
        curl --silent \
            --url-query key='<api-key>' \
            --url-query check="$addr" \
            'https://leakcheck.io/api/public'
    )

    if jq -e '.success' <<<"$reply"; then
        printf 'Address "%s":\n%s\n' "$addr" "$reply"
    fi
done <"$emails"
```

This reads addresses one by one from the file indicated by `$emails` and queries the API with each.  If the returned JSON document contains a top-level key `success` that has a non-false and non-null value, the address and the reply from the API are printed.  The test for success is done using `jq -e`, which exits with a value dependent on the value of the last evaluation in the `jq` expression (`.success` in this case).

Note that this code is not tested because I can't access the API endpoint.

---

The `jq` call could also be written as

```bash
jq -e -n --argjson reply "$reply" '$reply.success'
```

... which would allow us to run the script with `/bin/sh` instead of `bash` as we no longer would rely on the non-standard `<<<` "here-string" redirection.

If you are to process the data further, you may want to incorporate the address into the JSON (it's slightly odd that the address isn't already part of the reply from the API).  It's easier and safer to process JSON than processing a mix of text and structured JSON objects.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r addr; do
    reply=(
        curl --silent \
            --url-query key='<api-key>' \
            --url-query check="$addr" \
            'https://leakcheck.io/api/public'
    )

    jq -n \
        --arg addr "$addr" \
        --argjson reply "$reply" \
        '$reply | select(.success) | .address = $addr'
done <"$emails"
```

Since we don't have to use the shell for outputting the addresses now, we no longer need the `if` statement.  Instead, we `select()` the entry from the reply if it was successful and add the address to the object with the key `address`.  This means there will be no output for the unsuccessful replies.

An example of the output of this last variation of the script may be the following:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "found": 1,
  "passwords": 1,
  "sources": [
    {
      "name": "LinkedIn.com",
      "date": "2012-05"
    }
  ],
  "address": "test4@email.com"
}
{
  "success": true,
  "found": 1,
  "passwords": 1,
  "sources": [
    {
      "name": "LinkedIn.com",
      "date": "2011-05"
    }
  ],
  "address": "test5@email.com"
}
```

Use `jq` with its `-c` option if you don't want pretty-printed JSON as output:

```json
{"success":true,"found":1,"passwords":1,"sources":[{"name":"LinkedIn.com","date":"2012-05"}],"address":"test4@email.com"}
{"success":true,"found":1,"passwords":1,"sources":[{"name":"LinkedIn.com","date":"2011-05"}],"address":"test5@email.com"}
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe just `grep "true"` This will show you all lines that contain true. Theoretically, you can also simply add this to your bash script.

Comment: Note that this does not select the corresponding email addresses, and it would get the wrong values out if an address contained the substring `true`.  It would also do the wrong thing if any other part of the JSON part contains the substring `true`.